# Not able to generate more than 20 pages in wkhtmltopdf (approx)

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, nreco

I am trying to generate pdf with 30-35 pages using **wkhtmltopdf**, but there are blank pages after 20 pages(sometimes 21/22). To confirm this I have tried to generate same page 35 times using a loop (please note there is no error in html file).

I am using NReco.PdfGenerator (C#).

Comment: Am I understand correctly that you specify 30-35 URLs as input (with GeneratePdfFromFiles method)?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript profiler(chrome ) and optimize your code as much as possible if 
 wkhtmltopdf.exe throws timeout exception. 
 After doing refactoring based on above approach we also added 
  **--no-stop-slow-scripts** parameter along with 3 minutes timeout to the 
 wkhtmpltopdf exe. And now i can generate more than 80 pages :)

Comment: If you are using angular 2+ then this might help to optimize your code for better performance for pdf-

* Avoid method bindings in template, this executes for each event on the view and takes lots of time . It's recommended to bind variable to template instead of method.

* We can update angular change detection strategy by adding below lines of 
   code on each pdf specific component.

   @Component({
         // ...
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
   })

etc